# Genesis 11:9 The name was called Babel or Babylon?

Tags: genesis

Genesis 11:9 English Standard Version

> Therefore its name was called **Babel**, because there the LORD confused the language of all the earth. And from there the LORD dispersed them over the face of all the earth.

Christian Standard Bible

> Therefore it is called **Babylon**, for there the LORD confused the language of the whole earth, and from there the LORD scattered them throughout the earth.

Which translation is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operative word in Gen 11:9 is בָּבֶ֔ל = "Babel" which means both "confusion" and the proper name of the kingdom (see appendix 1 below).

Our modern English versions tend to follow the precedent of the LXX - see appendix 2 below.

**APPENDIX 1 - Brown-Driver-Briggs Entry for בָּבֶ֔ל = "Babel"**

בָּבֶ֫ל262 proper name, of a location Babel, Babylon (in Assyrian written Bab-ilu, gate of god DlPa 212, compare on other hand JenKosmol. 498) — with ָ  ה locative בָּבֶ֫לָה Ezekiel 12:13 +, בָּבֶ֑לָה 2 Kings 20:17 #NAME?מִבָּבֶ֫לָה Jeremiah 27:16; — the ancient capital of Babylonia, modern Hillah, situated on Euphrates, in long. approximately 440 30° east, and latitude approximately 320 50° north; Genesis 10:10; Genesis 11:9 (where name connected with בלל confuse, confound), both J, not elsewhere in Hexateuch; 2 Kings 17:24 31t. 2Kings; 18t. Chronicles; Esther 2:6; late Psalm 87:4; Psalm 137:1; Psalm 137:8; Isa2; Isa3, namely Isaiah 13:1,19; Isaiah 14:4,22; Isaiah 21:9; Isaiah 39:1,3,6,7; Isaiah 43:14; Isaiah 47:1; Isaiah 48:14,20; Micah 4:10 (but here probably not original, compare RSProph. vii. n. 5 & references) Zechariah 2:11; Zechariah 6:10; Daniel 1:1; Ezekiel 12:13 19t. Ezekiel; Jeremiah 20:4 (twice in verse); Jeremiah 20:5,6 165t. Jeremiah — note especially ׳אֶרֶץ בּ Jeremiah 50:28; also of land & people = realm, particular in ׳מֶלֶךְ בּ 2 Kings 20:12 of Merodach Baladan; 2 Kings 20:18; 2 Kings 24:1,7,11,12 (twice in verse) + often of Nebuchadrezzar; 2 Kings 25:27 = Jeremiah 52:31 compare Jeremiah 52:34 of Evil-Merodach; Nehemiah 13:6 of Artaxerxes; the city personified as בַּת בָּבֶל Isaiah 47:1; Jeremiah 50:42. (See DlPa 212 COT Genesis 11:9 KG95.)

בָּבֶל proper name, of a location Babylon (Biblical Hebrew id.); — Daniel 2:12 15t. Daniel; 9t. Ezra.

**APPENDIX 2 - Septuagint Translation**

The LXX is little help here in Gen 11:9 which reads:

> διὰ τοῦτο ἐκλήθη τὸ ὄνομα αὐτῆς Σύγχυσις, ὅτι ἐκεῖ συνέχεε Κύριος τὰ
> χείλη πάσης τῆς γῆς, καὶ ἐκεῖθεν διέσπειρεν αὐτοὺς Κύριος ἐπὶ πρόσωπον
> πάσης τῆς γῆς. = *On this account its name was called Confusion,
> because there the Lord confounded the languages of all the earth, and
> thence the Lord scattered them upon the face of all the earth.*

However, in the first instance of בָּבֶ֔ל = "Babel" in Genesis 10:10 we have:

> καὶ ἐγένετο ἀρχὴ τῆς βασιλείας αὐτοῦ **Βαβυλὼν** καὶ ᾿Ορὲχ καὶ ᾿Αρχὰδ
> καὶ Χαλάννη ἐν τῇ γῇ Σεναάρ. = *And the beginning of his kingdom was
> **Babylon**, and Orech, and Archad, and Chalanne, in the land of Senaar.*

We see this again in 2 Kings 17:24 and subsequently,

Καὶ ἤγαγε βασιλεὺς ᾿Ασσυρίων ἐκ **Βαβυλῶνος** τὸν ἐκ Χουθὰ ἀπὸ ᾿Αϊὰ καὶ ἀπὸ Αἰμὰθ καὶ Σεπφαρουαΐμ, καὶ κατῳκίσθησαν ἐν πόλεσι Σαμαρείας ἀντὶ τῶν υἱῶν ᾿Ισραὴλ καὶ ἐκληρονόμησαν τὴν Σαμάρειαν καὶ κατῴκισαν ἐν ταῖς πόλεσιν αὐτῆς. = *And the king of Assyria brought from **Babylon** the men of Chutha, [and men] from Aia, and from Aemath, and Seppharvaim, and they were settled in the cities of Samaria in the place of the children of Israel: and they inherited Samaria, and were settled in its cities.*

Thus, the LXX translated or transliterated the word בָּבֶ֔ל = "Babel" just as inconsistently as modern English versions.

Comment: You are mixing  two unrelated Hebrew words with similar spellings.

Comment: There is no dagesh on second ב - so it is not babel but bavel. It you choose not to follow Hebrew grammatical pronunciation, then why bother to include the niqudot? Also why did you blindly copy the cantillation mark?

Answer (score 3):

We read the following in hebrew:

> עַל־כֵּ֞ן קָרָ֤א שְׁמָהּ֙ **בָּבֶ֔ל** כִּי־שָׁ֛ם בָּלַ֥ל יְהֹוָ֖ה שְׂפַ֣ת
> כׇּל־הָאָ֑רֶץ וּמִשָּׁם֙ הֱפִיצָ֣ם יְהֹוָ֔ה עַל־פְּנֵ֖י
> כׇּל־הָאָֽרֶץ׃ {פ}

As **בָּבֶ֔ל** is pronounced *Babel*, thus the right pronounciation is the first one. Actually there is just a difference of language, both referring to the same city, this is, **Babylon** as in Greek Babylṓn (Βαβυλών) meaning (*Gate of G'd*), and *Bab* meaning gate togather with *El* which is G'd, so *Gate of G'd*. Both words have exactly the same meaning.

Another proof is that, the more than 200 times the word in hebrew appears in Old Testment, it's translated in Greek as *Babylon*. Concerning just the names mentioned and highlighted, both translations are **identical** (but of course, the proximity to hebrew is preferred).

Comment: Other source(s) for Bavel - "בָּב m.n. NH gateway, entrance. [From Aram. בָּבָא (q.v.).]" - Based on the Klein Dictionary. | בָּבֶל proper n. Babel, Babylon, Babylonia. [Akka. bāb-ilu (lit.: ‘the gate of god’). See בָּבָא and אֵל ᴵ.] -- https://www.sefaria.org/Klein_Dictionary%2C_בָּבֶל.1?with=Klein%20Dictionary&lang=bi

Comment: "בָּבֶ֔ל is pronounced Babel". There is no dagesh on second ב - so it is not babel but bavel.

Comment: Also why did you blindly copy the cantilation mark not necessary to the grammatical niqud?